. How Would I Go About ranking arrays in a numerical list based on the true value of one of its indices
Im Trying to Build a table that allows me to rank Baseball Players by their numerical Atrributes (1 - 100)by traversing through an array and ranking all said arrays by the value of the number at a set index. For example, if an array is var arr = [John James, Starting Pitcher, 88] and 88 is a number from 1 - 100 representing speed, how could a loop be set up to where a column labeled speed, when pressed, would rank the arr[2] of say 50 different arrays that all have a speed rating at the [2] index. The Code Below is the closest I have. Would I have to nest an array inside of an array in order to be able to rank these attributes?
https://www.theshowratings.com/lists/bunting-bunt this link is to a website that loosely has the same feature of ranking players by a set attribute. any help appreciated
for (I = 0; I < arr.length; I++){
if (arr[2] == 99.....

It would be easier to help if you showed more of your actual code and how the data is structured.

You might be looking for Array.sort, or maybe an order property on css grid / flex container. It will be difficult for anyone to help further without you providing what the input data looks like, and what the expected output should look like.

Given your description, I'm going to assume you have a two-dimensional array, something like this:
players = [
  ["Aaron Aaronson", "Position A", 90],
  ["Bob Butcher", "Position B", 80],
  ["Chris Carpenter", "Position C", 70],
];

The default JavaScript sorting behaviour is to convert each value (in this case, each row of the table) into a string, and sort them by their Unicode code point. In your case, this would amount to sorting the players alphabetically by their first names. In order to sort numerically by the third column, you need to provide a custom comparison function. This function should take two values: if the first value is smaller, it should return a negative number; if the first value is larger, it should return a positive number; and if both values are equal, it should return zero.
function compareSpeeds(a, b) {
  return a[2] - b[2]
}

// To sort your array of players:
players.sort(compareSpeeds)

If you had more numerical columns you wanted to be able to sort by, you could define a function that dynamically returns a comparison function for a specified column:
function cmpCol(col) {
  return (a, b) => a[col] - b[col];
}

// Sort by column 2
players.sort(cmpCol(2));

// Sort by column 3
players.sort(cmpCol(3));

The inner function returned by cmpCol is an arrow function. It doesn't have to be; you could do this instead:
function cmpCol(col) {
  return function(a, b) {
    return a[col] - b[col]
  }
}

...but having several stacked return statements like that can get a bit messy and difficult to read.
If, rather than a 2D array, you had an array of objects, your solution might look something like this:
players = [
  {
    name: "Aaron Aaronson",
    role: "Position A",
    speed: 90,
    height: 1.73
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Butcher",
    role: "Position B",
    speed: 80,
    height: 1.78
  },
  {
    name: "Chris Carpenter",
    role: "Position C",
    speed: 70,
    height: 1.75
  }
];

function cmpField(field) {
  return (a, b) => a[field] - b[field];
}

// Sort by speed
players.sort(cmpField("speed"));

// Sort by height
players.sort(cmpField("height"));

Note that the sort method modifies the original array (i.e. it sorts it in-place). If you'd rather create a new sorted copy of the original array, you can use toSorted, which otherwise works exactly the same way:
sortedPlayers = players.toSorted(cmpField("speed"));

If you also wanted the ability to sort by non-numerical fields (e.g. by name), this would require additional logic. This slightly more verbose version would work for anything that supports greater-than comparisons, including both strings and numbers:
function cmpField(field) {
  return function(a, b) {
    if (b[field] > a[field]) return -1;
    else if (a[field] > b[field]) return 1;
    else return 0;
  }
}

